# calling c functions from fortran, trouble with argc and argv

Tags: c, fortran

I'm **very** new to Fortran. Currently I'm writing (or trying to write) a fortran application which calls a C-library.

I've got a few things working so far but I'm stuck with the init-function from the library which expects argc and argv just to get the program name which is calling the function.

The C-library expects pointers to argc and argv:

```
void init(gint argc, gchar ***argv);
```

I have no idea how to express that ***argv in fortran. The other functions only need integers so I had no trouble using this skeleton for them:

```
interface
    subroutine init( argc, argv)
        ??
    end subroutine ee_init
end interface

call init( , )
```

Comment: Is gchar *** something like a two dimensional array of pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will probably need to write your own wrapper function in C, init_fortran, or similar which you call from Fortran and takes arguments in a way you can express in Fortran, then converts them to what the C init function expects.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using module ISO_C_BINDING and pass a pointer to an array of pointers, if i understand it correctly.