# Arrays of strings in Fortran-C bridges using iso_c_binding

Tags: c, interop, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I'm writing code that will call a C function from Fortran using Fortran's C interoperability mechanism (introduced in Fortran 2003 and implemented in newer versions of gfortran and ifort).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7964302/989692) is almost what I need, but I can't quite get my head around what interface declaration I should use in Fortran for a C function that looks like this:

```
int use_array(int n, char * array[]){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("Item %d = %s\n",i,array[i]);
    }
    return n;
}
```

I'm not clear what the declaration should be for the interface on the Fortran end:

```
interface
    function use_array(n, x) bind(C)
        use iso_c_binding
        integer (c_int) use_array
        integer (c_int), value :: n
        character(c_char) WHAT_SHOULD_GO_HERE? :: x
    end function use_array
end interface
```

I do know that I'll have to deal with the null-termination issue too.

Comment: Many thanks for user francescalus for helpfully editing this question to make me seem less polite by removing a "thank you" at the end of it.  Thank goodness users like them are around to stop people making questions unreadable with everyday courtesy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way we do it is to use a `C_PTR` array to point to strings. For example:

```
CHARACTER(LEN=100), DIMENSION(numStrings), TARGET :: stringArray
TYPE(C_PTR), DIMENSION(numStrings) :: stringPtrs
```

then we set our strings in `stringArray`, remembering to null-terminate them such as:

```
DO ns = 1, numStrings
   stringArray(ns) = "My String"//C_NULL_CHAR
   stringPtrs(ns) = C_LOC(stringArray(ns))
END DO
```

and pass `stringPtrs` to the C function.

The C function has the interface:

```
void stringFunc(int *numStrings, char **stringArray) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<*numStrings;++i) {
       printf("%s\n",stringArray[i]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks so much for the exceptionally quick and useful reply!  For completeness, the type in the interface is then "type(c_ptr), dimension(numStrings)"

Comment: Correct, in our code we don't actually provide an interface for the C-function, we treat it as `external` so I didn't have an easy example of the interface block on hand.

Comment: This is not standard Fortran 2003 (see section 15.2.1) or 2008 (section 15.3.2): **If the type is character, the length type parameter is interoperable if and only if its value is one.**. And gfortran signals this (using *character(len=...)* with C_LOC) as an error. There is also a [discussion](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36759) on this issue in GCC bugzilla.

Comment: An alternative made possible by Fortran 2018 is here: https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/t/return-an-array-of-strings-from-fortran-to-c/5100/7