# Passing an array of C-strings to Fortran (iso_c_binding)

Tags: c, string, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

How can I pass an array of C strings (`char* cstrings[]`) to a Fortran
subroutine?

Question [Arrays of strings in fortran-C bridges using iso_c_binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686532) is definitely related, but the answer does not seem correct and does not even compile with GNU Fortran.

I am currently working on a C interface for a Fortran code, and I expected that `iso_c_binding` (which I had used previously) would make this a piece of cake.  No luck so far for arrays of C strings...

The Fortran subroutine should take an array of strings as an argument.
In plain Fortran I would write something like the following:

```
subroutine print_fstring_array(fstring)

  implicit none

  character(len=*), dimension(:), intent(in) :: fstring
  integer                                    :: i

  do i = 1, size(fstring)
    write(*,*) trim(fstring(i))
  end do

end subroutine print_fstring_array
```

One way to pass a single C string to Fortran is as C pointer (`c_ptr`) (I know, I could also use an array of `character(kind=c_char)`)

```
subroutine print_cstring(cstring) bind(C)

  use iso_c_binding, only: c_ptr, c_f_pointer, c_loc, c_null_char
  implicit none

  type(c_ptr), target, intent(in) :: cstring
  character(len=1024), pointer    :: fstring
  integer                         :: slen

  call c_f_pointer(c_loc(cstring), fstring)
  slen = index(fstring, c_null_char) - 1
  write(*,*) fstring(1:slen)

end subroutine print_cstring
```

So, I assumed an array of `c_ptr` would be a good idea

```
subroutine print_cstring_array(n, cstring) bind(C)

  use iso_c_binding, only: c_ptr, c_int, c_f_pointer, c_loc, c_null_char
  implicit none

  integer(kind=c_int),               intent(in) :: n
  type(c_ptr), dimension(n), target, intent(in) :: cstring
  character(len=1024), pointer                  :: fstr
  integer                                       :: slen, i

  do i = 1, n
    call c_f_pointer(c_loc(cstring(i)), fstring)
    slen = index(fstring, c_null_char) - 1
    write(*,*) fstring(1:slen)
  end do

end subroutine print_cstring_array
```

but this produces a segmentation fault.

The C code for the last example is

```
# include "stdio.h"
# include "fstring.h"

void main(void) {
  char* cstring[] = { "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl" };
  int n = 4;
  print_cstring_array(&n, cstring);
}
```

and the contents of the header file `fstring.h` are simply:

```
void print_cstring_array(int* n, char* cstring[]);
```

I am targeting GNU Fortran and Intel Fortran and have tested the above with GNU Fortran.  The **lengths of the strings is fixed** (3 in the above example), in case this simplifies the solution.  However, the dimension of the array can vary.

Any pointers (even C pointers) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please note: `char* cstrings[]` is an array of **pointer** to "strings", it does not necessarily refer to a continous block of memory. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13869528/694576 and note the difference in how the "string" array is defined.

Comment: Thanks @alk. That might be the issue here. My C skills are not very good. How would I make it continuous?

Comment: "*How would I make it continuous?*" By doing it as the code in the question I linked does.

Comment: The google key for such issues is "*Mixed Language Programming*".

Comment: Thanks @alk, that link was not in your initial comment.  Indeed, that answer looks promising.  Now I am trying to grasp the details.

Comment: Also @alk, believe me that I have spent hours Google'ing for a solution. There are many forum posts that seemed related at first glance, but turned out not to be useful. This is in fact the first time that I resort to posting a question on SO.

Comment: Good luck. It simply is to long ago I did exactly this. The backup of the code is on backup of a backup ... sorry.

Comment: Which part you want to keep (more or less), your C code here, or your Fortran subroutine?

Comment: @alk - I solved it. I simply was not aware that `c_f_pointer(cptr, fptr[, shape])` takes an array shape as optional third argument (found in the answer you pointed to). You are welcome to post this as an answer.  Otherwise I will do myself, as I think it is useful for other people and not identical to the linked question.

Comment: @Vladimir - I am writing the Fortran part, but the C part should be as straightforward as possible for users.  Anyway, thanks to `alk` I have solved the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The largest problem in your code in the question is you use `c_f_pointer(c_loc(cstring),` instead of `c_f_pointer(cstring,`.

This works for me:

```
subroutine print_cstring_array(n, cstring) bind(C)

  use iso_c_binding, only: c_ptr, c_int, c_f_pointer, c_loc, c_null_char
  implicit none

  integer(kind=c_int),               intent(in) :: n
  type(c_ptr), dimension(n), target, intent(in) :: cstring
  character, pointer                            :: fstring(:)
  integer                                       :: slen, i

  do i = 1, n
    call c_f_pointer(cstring(i), fstring, [4])
    write(*,*) fstring
  end do

end subroutine print_cstring_array



# include "stdio.h"

void print_cstring_array(int* n, char* cstring[]);

void main(void) {
  char* cstring[] = { "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl" };
  int n = 4;
  print_cstring_array(&n, cstring);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  However, I think it is pure luck (or compiler dependent) that the call to `c_f_pointer` works in your example.  You definitely need the C memory location from `c_loc`.  See for example [`c_f_pointer` (Intel Fortran)](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-mac/GUID-7D76F195-E490-4765-B55E-32DF74168AE7.htm).

Comment: @alexurba No, it is OK. I pass `type(C_PTR)` to `c_f_pointer` which is of correct type. Your reference confirms that, although I know `c_f_pointer` quite well.

Comment: @VladimirF - I try to pass a 1-d `char *` : `char *cstring = {"hello world"};`, (skipping the `dimension(n)`  in declaration of cstring as well as the do-loop) and just using `call c_f_pointer(cstring, fstring, [lengthofcstring])` but all I get in fstring are lengthofcstring (=11) undefined pointers. Why is your last parameter in c_f_pointer = 4? Shouldn't it be 3?

Comment: Yes, 3, but 4 works too, the fourth null character is appended by C and is not printed.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the solution is easier than expected.  It turned out that `c_f_pointer(cptr, fptr[, shape])` takes an array shape as optional argument to convert arrays of C pointers (I missed that in the reference):

```
subroutine print_cstring_array(n, cstring) bind(C)

  use iso_c_binding, only: c_ptr, c_int, c_f_pointer, c_loc, c_null_char
  implicit none

  integer(kind=c_int),                 intent(in) :: n
  type(c_ptr), target,                 intent(in) :: cstring
  character(kind=c_char), dimension(:,:), pointer :: fptr
  character(len=3), dimension(n)                  :: fstring

  call c_f_pointer(c_loc(cstring), fptr, [3, n])
  do i = 1, n
     slen = 0
     do while(fptr(slen+1,i) /= c_null_char)
        slen = slen + 1
     end do
     fstring(i) = transfer(fptr(1:slen,i), fstring(i))
     write(*,*) trim(fstring(i))
  end do                                                

end subroutine print_cstring_array
```

Thanks to @alk for pointing me to [How to pass arrays of strings from both C and Fortran to Fortran?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13880611/1013199), because there I realized the optional `shape` argument of `c_f_pointer(cptr, fptr[, shape])`.

Comment: This looks overly complicated, what is `atom_types`? You don't declare it anywhere.

Comment: By calling `c_loc` you actually make pointer to a pointer. Your approach will fail once your array of strings will not be contiguous, i.e. when individual strings will be dynamically allocated.

Comment: Sorry for the `atom_types` - that was obviously a typo.  I now understand that I do not require `c_loc`. Your solution is the correct one. Thanks, @Vladimir.