# Pass dynamically allocated array of strings from C to Fortran

Tags: arrays, c, string, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am trying to pass a dynamically allocated array of strings (`char ***str`) from C to Fortran but I seem to be missing something when it comes to dereferencing the C pointer in Fortran thus yielding garbage strings as output (see MWE below).

### Side Question

Is calling `deallocate(fptr)` enough to stop the program below from leaking memory (I would think not)? If not would it be possible to free `msgs` (in C) from Fortran?

### To Reproduce

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void str_alloc(char*** msgs, size_t * n) {
  *n = 3;
  int str_len = 10;
  (*msgs) = malloc(*n * sizeof(char*));
  for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
    (*msgs)[i] = malloc((str_len + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy((*msgs)[i], "012346789");
  }
}
```

```
program main
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    interface
        subroutine str_alloc(msgs, n) bind(C, name="str_alloc")
            use iso_c_binding
            type(c_ptr), intent(out) :: msgs
            integer(c_size_t), intent(out) :: n
        end subroutine
    end interface

    integer, parameter :: STRLEN = 10
    character(kind=c_char, len=STRLEN), allocatable :: names(:)

    call str_array_from_c(names)

    contains
    subroutine str_array_from_c(strs)
        character(len=STRLEN), allocatable, intent(out) :: strs(:)

        type(c_ptr) :: cptr
        integer(c_size_t) :: i, n, lenstr
        character(kind=c_char, len=1), pointer :: fptr(:,:)

        call str_alloc(cptr, n)
        call c_f_pointer(cptr, fptr, [int(STRLEN, kind=c_size_t), n])
        allocate(strs(n))
        print*, "Output C-str array from fortran"
        do i = 1_c_size_t, n
            lenstr = cstrlen(fptr(:, i))
            strs(i) = transfer(fptr(1:lenstr,i), strs(i))
            print*, fptr(1:STRLEN, i), "|", strs(i)
        end do
        deallocate(fptr)
    end subroutine str_array_from_c

    !> Calculates the length of a C string.
    function cstrlen(carray) result(res)
        character(kind=c_char, len=1), intent(in) :: carray(:)
        integer :: res
        integer :: i
        do i = 1, size(carray)
          if (carray(i) == c_null_char) then
            res = i - 1
            return
          end if
        end do
        res = i
    end function cstrlen

end program main
```

#### Compile

```bash
gcc -c -g -Wall -o cfile.o cfile.c
gfortran -g -Wall -o main.o cfile.o main.f90
```

#### Output

```
 Output C-str array from fortran
 0�P�|0�
 p�|
 !|
```

### Additional Info

- I cannot edit the C interface.
- The C `str_len` in reality is variable and hence the array of strings is jagged. As far as I know, the only solution, without defining a custom type, is using a large enough `len=` of characters.
- I am relatively convinced that my mistake is how I dereference the pointer since inspecting the hex dump of `cptr` shows the strings are present

[image]

### Related posts

[How to pass arrays of strings from both C and Fortran to Fortran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869528/how-to-pass-arrays-of-strings-from-both-c-and-fortran-to-fortran)

[Passing an array of C-strings to Fortran (iso_c_binding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610236/passing-an-array-of-c-strings-to-fortran-iso-c-binding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the C side you have an array of pointers, which is NOT the same as a two-dimensional Fortran array. Fortran doesn't have the "array of pointers" concept, so you have to have an array of derived type with a pointer component.

First, the cptr returned from the C code has to be converted to an array of the derived type, each element of which contains a pointer to the string. You then iterate through each of these, converting the subcomponent C_PTR to a Fortran pointer, which is then your array of characters.

Second, you can't `DEALLOCATE` something that Fortran didn't allocate. You would have to call back into C to free those strings.

Here is a revised version of your Fortran code that works. The C code didn't change.

```
program main
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    interface
        subroutine str_alloc(msgs, n) bind(C, name="str_alloc")
            use iso_c_binding
            type(c_ptr), intent(out) :: msgs
            integer(c_size_t), intent(out) :: n
        end subroutine
    end interface

    integer, parameter :: STRLEN = 10
    character(kind=c_char, len=STRLEN), allocatable :: names(:)

    call str_array_from_c(names)

    contains
    subroutine str_array_from_c(strs)
        character(len=STRLEN), allocatable, intent(out) :: strs(:)

        type(c_ptr) :: cptr
        type,bind(C) :: c_array_t
            type(c_ptr) :: s
        end type c_array_t
        type(c_array_t), pointer :: c_array(:)
        integer(c_size_t) :: i, n, lenstr
        character(kind=c_char, len=1), pointer :: fptr(:)

        call str_alloc(cptr, n)
        call c_f_pointer(cptr,c_array, [n])
        allocate(strs(n))
        print*, "Output C-str array from fortran"
        do i = 1_c_size_t, n
            call c_f_pointer(c_array(i)%s, fptr, [int(STRLEN, kind=c_size_t)])
            lenstr = cstrlen(fptr)
            strs(i) = transfer(fptr(1:lenstr), strs(i))
            print*, fptr(1:STRLEN), "|", strs(i)
        end do
    end subroutine str_array_from_c

    !> Calculates the length of a C string.
    function cstrlen(carray) result(res)
        character(kind=c_char, len=1), intent(in) :: carray(:)
        integer :: res
        integer :: i
        do i = 1, size(carray)
          if (carray(i) == c_null_char) then
            res = i - 1
            return
          end if
        end do
        res = i
    end function cstrlen

end program main
```

When I build and run this I get:

```
 Output C-str array from fortran
 012346789|012346789
 012346789|012346789
 012346789|012346789
```